# How do I create a download link in GitHub Markdown?

Tags: html, github, markdown

I want to use links in a markdown file that one click download an RPM file. When I click the link, the page opens on GitHub.

Here is what I tried:

```
| Package                                                                                                              | Summery                    |
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | -------------------------- |
|  <a href="centos/8/x86_64/rpms/hello-2.10-1.el8.x86_64.rpm" download="hello-2.10-1.el8.rpm">hello-2.10-1.el8.rpm</a> | Hello, the rpm binary      |
|  <a href="centos/8/srpms/hello-2.10-1.el8.src.rpm" download="hello-2.10-1.el8.src.rpm">hello-2.10-1.el8.src.rpm</a>  | Hello, the rpm build files |
```

2nd

```
| Package                       | Summery                    |
| ----------------------------- | -------------------------- |
| [hello-2.10-1.el8.rpm][1]     | Hello, the rpm binary      |
| [hello-2.10-1.el8.src.rpm][2] | Hello, the rpm build files |

[1]: centos/8/x86_64/rpms/hello-2.10-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
[2]: centos/8/srpms/hello-2.10-1.el8.src.rpm"
```

Answer (score 1):

The relative link that you are using would resolve and redirect to the GitHub page of the particular file (note that it would redirect to `../blob/master/..`). You need to add the markdown with the link for the raw file (so that it would redirect to `../raw/master/..`) as below for it to be downloadable on click.

```
| Package                                                                                                              | Summary                    |
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | -------------------------- |
|  <a id="raw-url" href="https://github.com/joergklein/packages/raw/master/centos/8/x86_64/rpms/hello-2.10-1.el8.x86_64.rpm">hello-2.10-1.el8.rpm</a> | Hello, the rpm binary      |
|  <a id="raw-url" href="https://github.com/joergklein/packages/raw/master/centos/8/srpms/hello-2.10-1.el8.src.rpm">hello-2.10-1.el8.src.rpm</a>  | Hello, the rpm build files |
```

Alternatively, you can also use the hyperlink markdown instead of html as below

```
| Package                                                                                                              | Summary                    |
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | -------------------------- |
|  [hello-2.10-1.el8.rpm](https://github.com/joergklein/packages/raw/master/centos/8/x86_64/rpms/hello-2.10-1.el8.x86_64.rpm) | Hello, the rpm binary      |
|  [hello-2.10-1.el8.src.rpm](https://github.com/joergklein/packages/raw/master/centos/8/srpms/hello-2.10-1.el8.src.rpm)  | Hello, the rpm build files |
```

Comment: This worked for me (using raw). This is surprising that I did not find this recommendation made by the other Stack Overflow answers.

Answer (score 1):

In markdown links are shown like

```
[the text to be shown](https link)
```

so you can write it like

```
[hello-2.10-1.el8.rpm](https://github.com/joergklein/packages/raw/master/centos/8/x86_64/rpms/hello-2.10-1.el8.x86_64.rpm)
```

so as the .rpm can`t be open in the browser, they will be downloaded

And as you said it open the github page try to add https://raw.githubusercontent.com instead of https://github.com
Then it will work